# WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount throw Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i need to create a register page with entity framework and i trying to use websecurity class for userAuth system i coding for register this is code

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterUser model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Username, model.Password,
                new { FullName = model.FullName,
                      Email = model.Email,
                      Phone = model.Phone });
                WebSecurity.Login(model.Username, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and this is my model

```
    public class RegisterUser{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long and upto 15 characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Phone Number")]
    [StringLength(12,ErrorMessage = "Wrong Phone number",MinimumLength = 9)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

when i run and register with some data i got
RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

i try to check my value it all string and my model it string too
i don't why program throw like that 
anyone can help me?

Comment: what data type is `Phone` field in your db?

Comment: @AmarDuplantier Phone is string type i try to change every column to string but it still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. In my case, the issue was with the WebSecurity initialization WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection();

You must be using any string field for userIdColumn.

userIdColumn
The name of the database column that contains user IDs. This column must be typed as an integer **(int)**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134(v=vs.111).aspx